# AngularJS + Karma + Jasmine: how to prefix http requests with /base/www

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have some difficulties with my karma/jasmine configuration. I'm using the $httpBackend service from AngularJS to mock the backend, but I also use passThrough to allow angular to load local files. So in my unit tests I have something that looks like this:

```
beforeEach(module('myapp', 'ngCordovaMocks', 'ngMockE2E'));

beforeEach(inject(function(
    $httpBackend
) {
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    httpBackend.expectGET("https://my-backend.com/info").respond(200,"");
    httpBackend.whenGET(/^(?!http).*/).passThrough(); //any request that doesn't start with "http"
}));
```

So that my test makes some local requests to get some files. If I want this to works, I have to include and serve my files in the karma config, this is how I do it:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        preprocessors: { 'www/!(lib)/**/*.js': ['coverage'] },
        coverageReporter: {
            instrumenterOptions: {
                istanbul: { noCompact: true }
            }
        },
        reporters: ['mocha', 'kjhtml', 'coverage'],
        plugins: ['karma-*'],
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        browsers: ['Firefox', 'Chrome'],
        basePath: './',
        client: {
            captureConsole: false
        },
        //proxies:  {
        //    "/": "/base/www/"
        //},
        //urlRoot: "/base/www/",
        //baseUrl: "/base/www/",
        //basePath: "",
        files: [

            // [...] (lot of stuff)

            // I want those application files to be available :
            {pattern: "www/locales/locale-*.json", watched: true, served: true, included: false, nocache: true},
            {pattern: "www/**/*.html", watched: false, served: true, included: false, nocache: true},
            {pattern: "www/css/**/*.css", watched: false, served: true, included: false, nocache: true},
            {pattern: "www/lib/**/*.js", watched: false, served: true, included: false, nocache: true},
            {pattern: "www/cordova.js", watched: false, served: true, included: false, nocache: true},


            "tests/**/*.spec.js"
        ]
    });
};
```

However with this configuration, this is what I get when I try to run my tests:

```
20 07 2016 09:27:43.062:WARN [web-server]: 404: /tab/tabs.html
20 07 2016 09:27:43.063:WARN [web-server]: 404: /locales/locale-fr_FR.json
...
```

Of course it won't works! The file are served by karma at /base/www/stuff, and the application is making request at /stuff. So my questions is:

How can I prefix all requests from my unit tests with /base/www, so that a request to /stuff is resolved as being a request to /base/www/stuff? I'd also like a solution that only involve changes in configuration and/or unit tests and not changes in the application.

You can see in the karma config that I already tried to use some options:

- proxies: proxying the root (/) raise a warning and for a good reason, it can end up as an infinite loop when a request to /stuff is resolved as /base/www/base/www/base/www/[...]/stuff
- urlRoot: it does prefix all request from /stuff to /base/www/stuff, but the files are now at /base/www/base/www thus the request still fail.
- baseUrl: not sure what this options do. Can't see any effect...
- basePath: used to know where to find files, not helping at all.

---

Update: I'm using proxy until I can find anything better. I try to avoid anything that would trigger an infinite loops.

```
  proxies:  {
        "/": "/base/www/"
  },
```

---

Update: updated karma to 1.0 and changed config to:

```
  proxies:  {
        "/": "/base/www/"
  },
  urlRoot: "__karma__",
```

It seems to cause less problems but it will still spam with WARN [proxy] if it tries to reach a file that doesn't exist (favicon, etc.). As described here: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/2243